# Expectation of longest monotonic segment of a permutation

Tags: combinatorics

Consider for any $p \in P(n)$, the permutation group of order $n$, the function 
$L(p)$ defined as the length of the longest monotonic segment in $p$.  By this I mean that 
$$L(p) \geq k \Leftrightarrow \exists m \in \{1, \ldots ,n-k+1\} : \\
p_m < p_{m+1} < \cdots < p_{m+k-1} \text{ or } p_m > p_{m+1} > \cdots > p_{m+k-1}
$$
I'm looking for any sort of handle, for example, a recursion relation, on the number $N_L (n,k)$ of permutations in $P(n)$ that satisfy 
$L(p) = k$.

For example, with $n=6$,
$$
L(p= [2,1,4,5,3,6]) = 3
$$
based on the segment $(1,4,5)$.

In particular, I would like to be able to compute or understand the asymptotic behavior of the expectation value of $L(p)$, defined as 
$$
E(n) = \sum_{k} k \frac{N_L (n,k)}{n!}
$$

Note that longest increasing *segment* is different than the longest increasing *subsequence*, which has been shown to have an expectation value asymptoptic to $2\sqrt{n}$ (see MSE question 347072).  For the example permutation above, the longest increasing subsequence is of length 4
 $(1,4,5,6)$.

**Work I have tried**

A hand-waving argument hints that the asymptotic behavior is going to go as some constant times $\log(n)$.  Namely, when you try to extend $k$ to $k+1$ you have roughly a 50% chance of failing, so for the typical maximal monotonic length to increase by one, the size of the permutation would have to double.

If $A(n.k)$ is the number of permutations of length $n$ containing a monotonic segment of length at least $k$, then you can try to relate $A(n,k)$ to $A(n-1,k)$ as follows:

Choose any number from $1$ to $n$ as the first number.  Then do an order-preserving map of the remaining $n-1$ numbers to $\{1, \ldots, n-1\}$.  $A(n-1,k)$ of the resulting permutations will have a monotonic segment of length at least $k$, meaning that for those, the full permutation will also have such a segment.  So 
$$
A(n,k) = nA(n-1,k) + \sum_r B(n,r,k)$$
where  $B(n,r,k)$ is the number of permutations of length $n$ that start with a monotonic segment of length *precisely* $k-1$, beginning with $r$, and that contain no monotonic segment of length greater than of equal to $k$ (to avoid double counting.

It is easy enough to count the ways of starting with a monotonic segment of length $k-1$. The problem is, those ways interact with the condition of containing no other monotonic segment longer than $k-1$.  So I can't form a recursion that would get a handle on $B(n,k)$.    Still, the recursion ignoring the $B$ term gives some handle on a lower bound to $E(n)$.

But I am stuck at that point.

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~romik/download-book.php